# Material Button not filling whole width of screen

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

I am pretty new to the whole app development stuff, and I'm just trying to learn the basics. Especially with XML I only have very little experience.
My problem is, that I want to add a button, which expands over the whole width of the screen, but it just won't work and leaves some kind of margin around it. I have already tried a lot, but I couldn't find any solution, or maybe I just didn't know what to exactly search for. One tip I found with the android:insets attributes didn't work, except for top and bottom insets.

[image]

This is my component tree:

[image]

And this is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_2"
        tools:context=".ApplicationActivity">
    
        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/backBtn"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_btn_bg"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_thin"
            android:insetLeft="0dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetRight="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:text="@string/back_btn"
            app:backgroundTint="#470000"
            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_thin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope I included every information that's needed.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `layout_width` as `0dp` so that it can take whole available space between the constraints.

```xml
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

I also removed the `insetRight` and `insetLeft` tag. Here is the updated XML

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:text="Back"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#470000"
        app:cornerRadius="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: It unfortunately didn't change anything. There is still some space left and right to the button.

Comment: @Hubit Remove the insetLeft and insetRight, just keep the top and bottom inset and set width to 0dp. Also there are two font family tags. Remove one of them

Comment: I did it exactly as you described it. But it still doesn't expand all the way. And I read somewhere that for consistency between different devices you should add font family to android and app.

Comment: I would suggest you make a new layout once and try that again, you can add the font. I tried copying the same XML as you and it works for me.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I found out that my drawable caused the issue which I had assigned as the background. It for some reason had padding assigned to it. Thank your again for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this XML code

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/backBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back_btn_bg"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_thin"
        android:text="@string/back_btn"
        app:backgroundTint="#470000"
        app:cornerRadius="0dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_thin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Use 0dp  for `android:layout_width`

Comment: Same here, sadly no difference.